# Rollercoaster game with ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, physics, game-physics

I'm trying to simulate a rollercoaster game with ActionScript 3, but i don't know exactly if I should use a 2d engine (like Box2d) or do it from scratch.

For any of those I would like to see some code example.

Any ideas, pointers, suggestions... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should Box2D, and you can read documentation on official site. Try make Hello World example and you can see all power of this physics library. http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Comment: I'd agree that you should use box2d, physics are hard especially in flash. You might also want to take a look at http://www.kerp.net/box2d/ it's a good tutorial, and this for some help with the newest version: http://blog.allanbishop.com/category/physics/box2d/

Comment: Well at the end I'll use bezier curves instead a physics engine. But thanks for your help.